# The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook Login?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I'm trying to make a login with Facebook available in my script. I've done everything, but when I attempt to login with a Facebook account I get this error from Facebook:

> Error
>
> App Not Setup: The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook Login.

Here's error screenshot:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21775198/facebook-api-this-app-is-in-development-mode/37982567#37982567

Comment: @JigarDarji Guys, I'm looking for some 3-4 year old Facebook apps. Functionality doesn't matter. Just an old app. Please let me know if you got any.

Answer (score 686, accepted):

the problem was you have to set

> Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?

set `status and review` to `ON` and problem solved

enjoy coding

Comment: @PratikshaRaikundaliya But the web page notify me that I do not have a valid contact email specified. How should I solve this problem?

Comment: @JackieLam u have to ask another question by writing new topic to solve your problem

Comment: Another way of getting it working while you're developing is to make sure that any users that will be using the facebook app are added as testers/develoers/admins etc. (under the "roles" menu). That way you can keep the app private during development but still test out the functionality. Then just flick the switch when you go live.

Comment: Its under status and review. In case of anybody cannot find it

Comment: Hello I get to this option but the on/off button is disabled. and it says you must provide a valid contact email. where am i supposed to enter this email?

Comment: @NinjaDevelopers My facebook apps status is public to all users but still only developer can share. pls help me

Comment: this mean your app key is not for the same account you are using , make sure you are using same app key

Comment: @AlphaMale you have to add a contact email address. Do this in Settings -> Basic -> Contact Email.

Comment: @NinjaDevelopers I have the same issue,
My app is public
Contact email is also there
And this error comes for the admin account also by which the app is created
Can you please help...

Comment: Check this link https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10201756195602898 . you have to publish your app to make it public

Comment: @MikeyHogarth that should be an answer

Comment: Please also note that if you created a new app you need to replace all your previous APP_ID references with your new app's ID otherwise you will still get this error. You can do this with Notepad++ and replace all occurrences in your project directory with your new APP_ID.

Answer (score 635):

With respect to the all the other answers, here's the screenshot to help someone.

---

1. Go to https://developers.facebook.com/

---

2. Click on the Apps menu on the top bar.

---

3. Select the respective app from the drop down.

[image]

The circle next to your app name is not fully green. When you hover mouse on it, you'll see a popup saying, "Not available to all users because your app is not live."

So next, you've to make it publicly available.

---

4. Click on setting at left panel. [see the screenshot below]

[image]

---

5. In Basic tab add your "Contact Email" (a valid email address - I've added the one which I'm using with developers.facebook.com) and make "Save changes".

---

6. Next click "App Review" at left panel. [see the screenshot below]

---

7. Look for this, **Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?** and Turn ON the switch next to this.

[image]

---

8. That's it! - App is now publicly available. See the fully green circle next to the app name.
   [image]

Answer (score 161):

Since the UI of the facebook has changed recently, here's the latest update for setting the sandbox mode ON/OFF :

1. Go to https://developers.facebook.com/
2. Click on the Apps menu on the top bar.
3. Select the respective app from the drop down.
4. Go to 'Status & Review' from the table in the left side of the page.
5. Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public? - Select switch to set YES/NO value.

**Update:** 
The YES/NO button will be disabled until and unless you provide your contact email.

1. Go to "Settings" in the left menu.
2. Update your Contact Email.
3. Hit the "Save" button at the bottom of the page.

**Update:** 
'Status & Review' is replaced by 'App Review' now

Answer (score 37):

If the app is still in **private** mode (`Status and Review` set to **NO**), then **only** Facebook users with role in the app can login. 
That unless you set it to **public** (`Status and Review` set to **YES**).

To add more users to be able to login to a private app:

1. Go to https://developer.facebook.com
2. Go to Apps ->  "Your app" -> Roles
3. Choose Add Administrator,Developer or Tester.

Answer (score 18):

Many reasons including:

1. Sandbox mode is ON
2. Domain name is different
3. Site URL is different.

Comment: Where to get the domain name, for my case it is an ionic 4 cross platform app running on a website as a web app and on devices (not uploaded to play store yet)

Answer (score 16):

This error also occurs when you try to log in in your **test version of the Facebook app** and you have not added the user you are trying to test the log in with in the **Roles -> Testers** section.

To fix it, just **add the email address of the Facebook account you are trying to log in with** in the section above.

Finally, make sure the user you added accepts the request sent before you try to test otherwise the log in process will fail in the second screen just after the user accept the conditions.

Answer (score 9):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Make Sure in left panel App review tab selected (Your app is currently live and available to the public.) tab is **ON** and App status is **GREEN**

Happy Programming

Answer (score 9):

And addition to all these beautifull comments dont forget to Start A Submission

[image]

Answer (score 8):

There are a bunch of possible things which could trigger this error:

In your case, you just need to `add your facebook account into either tester, developer or admin of your facebook app` as you want to use that account to test.

But if you see the error upon clicking `connect to facebook`(before you have chance to enter facebook credentials), then it means your current facebook account detected from cookie is not a valid tester/developer/admin account for your app.
Your could either `add your account in` or just `hit facebook.com and sign out(to remove the undesired cookie)`.

Comment: so simple, so hard to get it when the problem occurs. tnx.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem but now here is how I solved it
Go to https://developers.facebook.com/
•  Click on the Apps menu on the top bar.
•  Select the respective app from the drop down.
•  Click Settings from the table in the left side of the page
•  Then under the Contact Email type in your email you would like to use
•  Then click save settings  button
•  Go to 'Status & Review' from the table in the left side of the page.
•  Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public? - Select switch to set YES/NO value.

Answer (score 6):

For other users that run into this issue, the app I was testing against was a test version of our production app and didn't have the option to turn `status and review` to `ON` as others have mentioned here.

The fix was to create a new app which is *not* a test app, and configure it like the production version. The non-test version allows the option to turn `status and review` to `ON`.

My specific use was testing a user registered with a phone number instead of an email address. I tried adding that user into different roles of our test app (Developer and Tester), but to no avail. My guess is it has something to do with the user not having an email associated with it.

Here's more info on test apps: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps

Answer (score 6):

Hemang's answer was right, BUT, there's one extra step you'll need, which is to add a Facebook App ID. (I discovered I was missing this part):
[image]

Once you've done that in addition to Hemang's answer, you'll be good to go!

Answer (score 5):

Okay - sandbox is off, domain has to be correct because 99% of the users can reach the app, and "all its live features available to the general public" is set to yes.

Answer (score 5):

Now, You need to add a "Privacy Policy URL" in the App Details tab (developers.facebook.com).
This is a new Policy of Facebook.

Answer (score 4):

This resolved my issue if you do not want to make the app available to the public (keeping Status & Review on **NO**)

I  had to sign out of the previous account on the **Facebook App** and also remove the Facebook account in **Settings**. Removing just from the Settings will not remove the error because the App itself still has the previous account logged in.

If  you have set your Roles as Administrator/Developer/Tester, you can put in that account login info in and it should work then.

Answer (score 3):

do setup by following bellow link and domain name you need to mention as like wht you have mentioned in facebook app domain name.

Go to https://developers.facebook.com/

Click on the Apps menu on the top bar.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you didn't make your Facebook app live. For this go to:

> Facebook developer page->Select your app->you will see top of the right your live option is disable and click to enable it->It will refer to you in "basic setting section"->You have to add "privacy policy url" and "Terms and services url" also you may select app category->then save the setting.

Note: You can use any blogspot or website to make your privacy policy also terms and condition  page.Both I gave same url which worked.

[image: Toggle button for Facebook app live]

Comment: You are my hero but i checked your message after doing this task. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: sir in my case Live lable is not visible in my case only showing Developement  can you tell me sir why its not showing?

Answer (score 0):

after a lot of tries, I've read in other topics which someone said "delete all your apps and create it again". I did that but, as you can imagine, a new App will create a new Application ID on Facebook's page.

So, even after all the "set public things" it didn't work because the application ID was wrong in my code due to the creation of a new App on Facebook developer page.

So, as AndrewSmiley said above, you should remeber to update that in your app @strings

Comment: Never delete the app. It can be confugured change version as i ansered on, check it out ... if you delete it, you cannot use the old version, on app created version is the most recent, so need update alllll your code......... change sdk, change calls, change, specify api, version, ... Its better to use test apps ok .

Answer (score 0):

Set LoginBehavior if you have installed facebook app in your phone

loginButton.setLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.WEB_ONLY);