# Facebook API "This app is in development mode"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

What does "development mode" mean for a facebook app? I find no exact explanation of what I can and can't do while in development mode and what's the relation with the "Not available to all users because your app is not live".

Some people also refer to it as "Sandbox mode" so I have a lot of confusion between "development mode", "sandbox mode", "live vs not available to general public"

Comment: Those basically all mean the same – while an app is in sandbox mode/development mode, so “not live”, only the users added as admins, developers, testers to the app can use it and see content that was created through it. Only when you put it in live mode, every user will be able to use it and see content made via it.

Comment: I think this answer will answer you question
[Active facebook app to all user][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329250/the-developers-of-this-app-have-not-set-up-this-app-properly-for-facebook-login?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Important: Make sure you have a plan for if your app loses 'live' mode. My app lost live mode a month ago due to a missing privacy policy and my 'login with facebook' functionality failed for live users - for myself and my test users it worked but I didn't even notice for a month. I'm now going to implement a daily check for the status.

Comment: that's what happened to me @Simon_Weaver, facebook should at least notify via email. has anyone identified an option to be notified or keep track of the app's status?

Comment: Welp, development mode and live mode have now been replaced with Access Levels. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/access-levels/

Answer (score 209):

I know its a little bit late but someone may find this useful in future.

**STEP 1:**

Login to facebook Developer -> Your App

In **Settings** -> **Basic** -> **Contact Email**. (Give any email)

**STEP 2:**

And in '**App Review**' Tab : change

Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public? **Yes**

And you app will be live now ..

Comment: How long this might take for this action to take effect. I update setting about 10- min ago still can't login.

Comment: After this also the app is showing invalid key hash error, i have already given the release key to the Facebook settings.
Please suggest me what to do?

Answer (score 43):

[image: App Review > Make {Your App} public? > Yes]

Click app review and Turn on the Make your app Public toggle. Save changes

Comment: what is the url for this?

Answer (score 24):

```
This problem occurs when we set our app as unavailable to the public.
```

**STEP 1**

Open Facebook developer account

https://www.facebook.com/login/?next=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Ffacebook-login%2Fios

[image]

**STEP 2**

Select your application

[image]

**STEP 3**

Click the app Review tab.

[image]

Change switch value no to yes. See picture below.

[image]

After this your app is live.

Answer (score 14):

- `Development mode` is for testing
- Go to `https://developers.facebook.com/apps`, then `App Review` -> Select `No` for `Your app is in development and unavailable to the public`
- Go to `Roles` -> `Testers`, enter the `Facebook user Id` of the users you want to enable testing

Answer (score 11):

Follow these basic steps to fix this problem,

> **Step 1:** Go to **Dashboard**,
>
> **Step 2:** Go to **"App Review"** tab,
>
> **Step 3:** Enable the **"Make test public?"** option, Like Below image,
>
> [image]

Answer (score 4):

I had also faced the same issue in which my FB app was automatically stopped and users were not able to login and were getting the message "app is in development mode.....".

Reason why FB automatically stopped my app was that I had not provided a valid PRIVACY policy & terms URL. So, make sure you enter these URLs on your app basic settings page and then make your app PUBLIC from app review page as described in above posts.

Answer (score 3):

in your app dashboard check status to on
[image: facebook change develope mode to live]

Comment: Sir my account developement mode is not showing instead showing business.can you tell ne sir why it's not showing development mode?

Comment: @Kapilsoni click on change app type at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 1):

for testing purposes only you could Go to your facebook developer dashboard.
create your app then in the top left corner open the apps dropdown menu and click *create test app* take the app ID and use instead.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem while integrating the Facebook SDK for login.

I'm suggesting below approach for development mode  > you can test all things if you are login with same account, which is used for 'developers.facebook.com' and if you want to use another accounts then you need to add Roles for that particular app, for that you can add developer or testers by using fid or facebook username.

Eg: - Select the particular app > Roles and then add developer or testers.

[image]