# Cannot log in to my android application using facebook SDK

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook

I am running an emulator on Eclipse to test an android application. Here is the screenshot after I enter my login info and click login:

[image: fb]

I have followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379890/android-facebook-sdk-4-in-eclipse). I have used the code at the bottom of the page [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started) to get my developer key hash and have entered that key into the facebook developer settings. Is there something I am missing?

EDIT:

I want to run the activity as a "sample"

Comment: Hi Lokor, I think this question is your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21775198/facebook-api-this-app-is-in-development-mode

Comment: How do I add myself as a test user and/or how do I create a test user?

Comment: In App Dashboard, you can add tester role. You can find more information here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What got it to work was create an app in my developer account, then Add Platform under Settings, and then enter the key hash into the Key Hash field.

Previously I was just entering the Key Hash into Developer Settings > Samples, which wasn't working. I thought I could run my app as a sample.

It did not require me to set the app as public. It remained in Development Mode.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable your app for public ,

1. Login to your developer account
2. Select your app and go to "Status and Review" from left side tab list
3. There is a switch mentioning with "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?" , switch in to yes.

Comment: I don't want it to be available to the general public. I just want to log into it via my android emulator in Eclipse.