# Application testers and access to app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have added some colleagues as [testers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/managing-development-cycle) in my Facebook app (I don't want to make it public yet). They look correct in the Facebook app dashboard, but when I try to access the app, I get an error

> App Not Setup: This app is still in development mode, and you don't have access to it. Switch to a registered test user or ask an app admin for permissions.

I have tried to figure if there's something wrong with my setup, including

1. use the app via https, not http
2. ensured the user I'm testing the app with is a developer in Facebook, not a regular (non-developer) user

The proposals about making the [app public](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21775198/facebook-api-this-app-is-in-development-mode) are not suitable, as we wish not to make the app available to the world.

Comment: Did the users accept your request to make them developers of the app?

Comment: Should testers get invitations? Didn't see anything in those users Facebook notifications nor on Facebook dev center notifications.

Comment: Yes, they need to confirm the request you send them.

Comment: Based on my experience: one does not accept app tester rights nor is there any notification.