# Facebook login error: This app is still under development mode while it's already set to public mode

Tags: android, facebook, api

**I cannot upload any photos, relevant photos are added via links.**

I've recently integrated facebook login into my mobile application
but when I try to login from the administrator user, i.e with my facebook account, I'm getting the following error:

[PHOTO: App is still under development mode error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUnSx.jpg)

I've tried the solution described here but no success.

[Facebook API "This app is in development mode"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21775198/facebook-api-this-app-is-in-development-mode)

I cannot upload more then 2 so I'll just note that:

1. I've provided a valid email in my facebook settings page.
2. I've set my app live in the App Review page.
3. This app is not in the store and still under development.
4. From some reason, I'm getting the above error even as the administrator of the app that suppose to be able to test it while it's under development.

this is the code that creates to login request:

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private String TAG = LoginActivity.class.getSimpleName();
final CallbackManager fbCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    ActivityLoginBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_login);
    binding.fbLoginButton.registerCallback(fbCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Facebook loging returned details: " + loginResult.toString());
            //LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(LoginActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile"));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Facebook loging was cancelled");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Facebook login error: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    });
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    fbCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

}

**I'll really appreciate your help with this one**

**Ariel**