# My App has been given the pages_messaging permission but only receiving messages from testers

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I did a Facebook Messenger chatbot which after submitting for review and the pages_messaging submission approved, I am still only able to receive messages from testers.

Comment: did you make app public ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click app review and Turn on the Make your app Public toggle

[image]

Source: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39947168/5437621)

Comment: Oh, found it in the App review Tab!