# Passport-facebook login error

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, passport-facebook

My app is in live mode but still getting the following error sms :

> Your app is not configured. This app is still in development mode, and
>   you  don't have access to it. Switch to a registered test user or ask
>   an app admin  for permissions.

I have read all the related solutions but unable to solve the problem.
I have put the urls for privacy policy and terms from https://termsfeed.com

I get this answer is the best for related question but getting same error:
[Facebook API "This app is in development mode"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21775198/facebook-api-this-app-is-in-development-mode)

I am using nodejs for development

Comment: First of all double check that you are really using the correct app id in your code.

Comment: @CBroe yeah! i am using the correct app id and app secret !
i have rechecked it !
Thanks for your quick response !

Comment: Well then you’ll have to give us some actual specific information about the problem ... screenshot from your settings, URL of where you are using this, …

Comment: yeah sure !
actually i am using localhost for development and as an admin , i am able to login successfully but when i try to login by using some other valid credentials.. i get that error sms that your app is not live..
this is the actual problem !

@CBroe in short, i am unable to login with other valid credentials although my app is public and live mode