# Facebook Login: App is not setup in android studio

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.x, signed-apk

My App is already in Live mode.

Added email inside (Settings->Basic->Contact Email).

Still not working Facebook login in my Released Apk(Published in Alpha Stage in Playstore)...showing the following error,

Error:

```
App Not Setup:This app is still in development mode, and you don't have access to it.Switch to a registered test user or ask an app admin for permissions.
```

Comment: create sha1 key using you publish keystore.key and add into facebook developer console .

Comment: @suman Yes ...that also i have created and saved in facebook developer console.....still the same error i'm getting

Comment: It should work .Create a Launch activity and create editext and button.add click event in button and paste code snipet in click event and set text in EditText.Copy Sha1 key from edit text and paste in developer console.You should make release build with keystore.key. Enjoy it, Happycoding

Comment: are you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21775198/facebook-api-this-app-is-in-development-mode

Answer (score 0):

**Step1:**
Please ensure the app is in production mode.
Please refer screenshot.

[image]

**Step2:**
In Settings -> Basic -> Contact Email. (Give your/any email).

Hope this will help.