# Social login error occurred when try to login

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, social-authentication

I am working on android social login integration, I followed up the [facebook official documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/)

All worked correctly but I get the following error when trying to log in.

[image: error on screen]

My code snippet is here

```
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            // App code
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
            Log.v("LoginActivity", "cancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
            Log.v("LoginActivity", exception.getCause().toString());
        }
    });
```

Please try to help!

Comment: try as user with a role in the app, or make it public. the error message is very clear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook API "This app is in development mode"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21775198/facebook-api-this-app-is-in-development-mode)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @luschn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to Facebook developer console and change your app availability to general public

Answer (score 3):

follow this steps

1)visit facebook developer console and Go to Settings then Basic then Contact Email and write down you any email.

2)inside 'App Review' Tab you must change
Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public? Yes