# You may not make your app available to all users Facebook dashboard

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, social-networking

Not able to change Facebook app mode `Development` to `Live` in the Facebook developer console.

Also, there is no error display.

[image]

While trying to live mode it shows the tooltip "**You may not make your app available to all users**".

Also, try below link solution but not work.

[Facebook API "This app is in development mode"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21775198/7271027)

Comment: Did you get everything that needs reviewing, successfully reviewed already?

Comment: Yes, everything was reviewed successfully  @CBroe

Comment: Do you have any alerts in your dashboard about the app being disabled by Facebook? Cause that is the only scenario among my own apps where I can find the app mode switch disabled like this. (Other than scenarios where it actually alerts me to some missing settings.)

Comment: Yes, there was one required action `Platform Term 7.d` but that was resolved now.