# Windows Phone 8 C# facebook app registration

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, windows-phone-8, facebook-login

Hi I've created an app for Windows Phone 8 using the ContosoSocial Facebook login interface.
It uses the following call to do this:

```
FacebookSessionClient fb = new FacebookSessionClient(AppId);
fb.LoginWithApp("basic_info,publish_actions,read_stream", "custom_state_string");
```

This works fine when I use the default AppId but when I change it to the one given by Facebook following app registeration I get the following error:

> Given URL is not premitted by the application cofiguration.: One or more of the given URL's is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the website URL or Canvas URL, or the app domain must be a subdomain of one of the Apps domains..?

I've searched and this problem has come up on several occations and as far as I can work out it's to do with my app settings on Facebook.? Facebook asks for an App Domain which I've left blank as I'm not sure what this is or used for..? Do I need one..?

I've followed several tutorials Scrumptious but then all show a different app registration process on the screens than I'm faced with. A little research revealed that Facebook has recently changed the process which is making it even more confusing for me. I would appreciate some help here.

I want to create an app which will pull in a news feed direct into a panoramic item on the app's main screen.

Many thanks

EDIT: I've tried adding my web site URL to the app domain by I get the following error: This must be derived from Canvas URL, Secure Canvas URL, Unity Binary URL, Site URL, Mobile Site URL, Page Tab URL or Secure Page Tab URL. Check and correct the following domains: ***************

Below is the screen shot for configuring app:

[image]

Store ID, Application Name & Windows Store Beta ID removed, I'm now getting the following error:
App Not Setup: The developers of this app have not setup the app properly for Facebook Login. ?

Comment: What all platforms does your app support?

Comment: I've added a Windows App on Facebook registration

Comment: `I've added a Windows App on Facebook registration`- can you show how

Comment: Great. You've posted a wrong link, here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329250/the-developers-of-this-app-have-not-set-up-this-app-properly-for-facebook-login

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Advanced Settings** in your developers.facebook.com/apps/ of your app and check that "**Embedded browser OAuth Login**" is enabled and set to **Yes**.