# App Not Setup: The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for facebook login even app was released

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, error-handling, unity-game-engine

I developed a game by Unity 4.3 with Facebook Official SDK Plugins for Unity, and the game was released a few weeks ago, and work fine. However, I got a few report that players cannot login to facebook and got this error message. I tried to logout from facebook and login again, but I got this error.

I am very sure that my facebook app is NOT in sandbox mode and the option is YES in status and review, but I still get this error. any idea for me ?

Thanks you !

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook Login?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329250/the-developers-of-this-app-have-not-set-up-this-app-properly-for-facebook-login)

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure for below points to be correct:

1. Is your app submitted in developers.facebook.com
2. Have you filled correct details of the app in developers.facebook.com.
3. Is the app made Live for all users in developers.facebook.com.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to Settings tab, and enter the Contact email address. Then the app goes to live, and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Do This:

Your App is not Live for All User's, so make it Public.
Follow the below steps:

1. Go to Apps and select your APP.
2. click on the Status & review.
3. select "YES" access public.
4. click confirm button to finished.

Now your app will be public.

Run the code :)

Hope it will help you.