# Facebook login error: "The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook login"

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I've been seeing error like this when trying to use Facebook Login.

[image]

I've checked everything including setting up the pList

[image]

and followed solutions in this link
[The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook Login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329250/the-developers-of-this-app-have-not-set-up-this-app-properly-for-facebook-login)

by setting the "
Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?" to YES

[image]

but then this image came up.

[image]

When I first try doing facebook login there's no need to even turn the live feature available to YES to make it work I wonder what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys i found the solution, just go to facebook on your safari in the iOS simulator and log out the current user or test user and create a new test user. It should work!