# Facebook Friends Work History

Tags: php, facebook

I'm testing the following:

```
me/friends?fields=id,name,work
```

With Facebook Grpahi Api Explorer application is working but with mine is returning an empty array.

I only need user_friends permission, but I tried with:

```
'user_friends,   user_work_history,read_friendlists'
```

Any ideas ?

I tested and the following and is not working too

```
me/friends?fields=id,name
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question:

```
set status and review to ON and problem solved
```

[The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook Login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329250/the-developers-of-this-app-have-not-set-up-this-app-properly-for-facebook-login)