# facebook app: permissions request gives blank page

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

This is my first post on StackOverflow.

I've been trying to start a facebook app but I had some trouble granting permissions. When I use the example provided on the [facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.1#quickstart), it works as expected with the developper's account but not with another account. Using another account, I can enter my credentials but then, instead of a page requesting for permissions, I see a blank page.

Any idea what can be the problem ? I have tried to add a Site-URL in my app's settings but I couldn't make it work so far..

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am trying to figure this one out as well, your question helped since you mentioned that is did work for the developer's account. I tried and added a tester accounts on https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{your app-id}/dashboard/and they work too..

**EDIT:**

I found the answer thanks to you. See: [The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook Login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329250/the-developers-of-this-app-have-not-set-up-this-app-properly-for-facebook-login)