# The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook Login

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I have Facebook app and want to allow users log in on my website.

I've read all answers on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329250/the-developers-of-this-app-have-not-set-up-this-app-properly-for-facebook-login) and [FaceBook community](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10201756195602898) but they cannot solve problem.

In my facebook app settings:

- In "Dashboard" i see status "Live and available to all users"
- In "Status & Review" public mode set to "Yes"
- Email is correct
- No alerts
- Double checked app secret
- Domain added as `example.com`
- Platform "Website" also set up with url `http://www.example.com/` (mobile is set too with exactly same url)
- Permissions "email", "public_profile" and "user_friends" are in
  status "Live and available to all users" (block "Approved Items")

Trying to login from working site.

How can i fix this?

UPD. This was my inattention – app id was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the correct Platform in the App Settings too.

```
Settings > Add Platform
```

Comment: Updated question with additional info about configuration. Yep, platform also set with valid url to my site root `http://www.example.com/`

Comment: did you set the mobile url too?

Comment: btw, you only need "example.com" in the app domains field, it will work for subdomains too and you don´t need www.example.com either.

Comment: Yes, mobile url is set up too (same as main).
Also, updated facebook settings "App Domains" field with only `example.com`.
This doesn't fix error.

Comment: i see that you checked the app secret. did you check the app id too? that´s even more important. you only need the secret on the server.

Comment: Oh, my.. You're right. AppId was different. This solves my inattention, thank you!

But, i have now secondary question. This app was working normally (about half year). App id can be autochanged by Facebook?

Comment: not really, no. and you can only change the app secret afaik - which is only useful for security reasons, if the secret is compromised. but i am happy to help :)