# How to correctly set up development version of Facebook app on localhost for Facebook login?

Tags: ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, heroku, koala

I have made a Facebook app in Ruby (using Sinatra and Koala), deployed it on Heroku and sat up all the settings and it works that way, but now I have to debug some functionality and for that reason I need to run application from localhost (using `foreman start`).
I have read somewhere that I should make development version of my app and specify `site url` to `localhost:[port_num]` and I have done so.

- The problem is when user(me) reach `localhost:5000` and application redirects it to Facebook to get permissions (when Facebook login dialog should appears). At that point this error occurs:

  App Not Set Up: The developers of this app have not set it up properly for Facebook Login.

I saw this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329250/the-developers-of-this-app-have-not-set-up-this-app-properly-for-facebook-login#21329790) but in my development version of app there is no `status and review` settings and I don't see how to make application alive.

[image]

- How to set up my app for Facebook Login while it runs on localhost?

or

- What is the proper way to run Facebook app from localhost to get full functionality?

Comment: Can you just try running it on the standard HTTP port 80? Maybe the custom port is creating some problems.

Comment: Probably won't work without a HTTPS connection, you can use a tunneling service like ngrok.com.

Comment: I just tried ngrok.com and now it produces different error:
"Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."

Comment: you don´t need https for external websites, only for page and canvas apps

Comment: I forgot to mention - before I tried to open 33d3c44f.ngrok.com I have set App Domain and Site url of development version of app to 33d8d04f.ngrok.com. And the error is:"iven URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem laid in Advanced settings in security section - development app "inherits" settings from base app so in `Settings->Advanced->Security->Valid OAuth redirect URIs` was initially url of my base app not my `localhost:5000` and it causes a problem. One of solutions is to leave this field empty (and leave app open to redirect attacks) or to fill this field with your `Site URL`.

- It seems that development version of an application can't be "alive".
- To allow Facebook Login for users of your development app you should register them as testers under `Roles` tab.