# Android application: Unable to Login with Facebook in Development mode

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform, facebook-login, android-facebook

I am using ParseFacebookUtils to provide log in feature in my Android Application. I have successfully integrated Facebook and Parse SDK's. I do not want to make the application created on Facebook live to public yet, because it is still under development.

ISSUE:
I am unable to Login to the app when I provide any Facebook Log in credentials EXCEPT for the application administrator's credentials. If I provide any other credentials, I get the following error shown right after Facebook Log in Screen:

App not setup: the developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook  .

How can I enable many users to log in to the app without assigning them any role through the Facebook dashboard?

Comment: Check facebook developer page, you need to confirm your app to facebook otherwise you can't take permissions from other users.

Comment: By confirming to facebook, do you mean making all its live features available to the general public (Under Status & Review section )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check Hemang answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329250/the-developers-of-this-app-have-not-set-up-this-app-properly-for-facebook-login), it well explained.You need provide valid email address and make the app available to general public on facebook developer page though it is in testing mode.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, basically what I am trying to achieve cannot be done without Status and Review set to YES. Now I have to add users under the Roles section, as explained in the link you shared.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**
  Check your `keystore` is proper.Verify it.

**Solution 2**
what type of permissions you requested. If some permissions needed to be approved then you have to upload the apk and get approved.

**Solution 3**
 Try to use SimpleFacebook Library. Its quite simple.