# Facebook - default app visibility and info missing in insights

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights, facebook-permissions

I am working on getting our app into good shape Facebook-wise and there are two issues I cannot seem to figure out no matter how hard I try.

1. Is there any way to change the **Default App Visibility**? When our users sign up with Facebook, the default app visibility is set to *Only Me*. Is there any way to change this or does it depend on user's personal settings? Or can it be done from the mobile app somewhere in the e.g. Facebook SDK session?
2. We have been using Facebook for a while and in the Insights under the Login tab, there is the Demographics of New Facebook Logins section. I can see still the Geography data but for Gender & Age I now get *No data is available for the current selection.* even though I swear it worked about a month ago or so. Any ideas?

Any kind of advice or help is more than appreciated, seriously!

Comment: Check the link if it works for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329250/the-developers-of-this-app-have-not-set-up-this-app-properly-for-facebook-login

Comment: I should have stated this clearly in the question, sorry. The app is live and has been for about two years now. We have done a few minor updates to the settings (switched off country restriction) and major refactoring on the client side (iOS and Android) and suddenly, it is not possible get the insights for Gender & Age. The default visibility has been bugging me for some time now so I thought I should ask that too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you're only requesting read permissions, then there's no way to change the default audience (it's not really meaningful anyways in that case). If you're requesting publish permissions (like publish_actions), then you can set a default audience when you're making the request. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/Session.NewPermissionsRequest/#setDefaultAudience This can only be done once, and the user can always change it to a different setting later or deny that request, so you should not rely on it being the value that you chose in code. There's also no way to see or detect (from your app) what the user changed it to later, this is by design.
2. You're likely getting "No data is available" because there's not enough usage (or individual users) in that date range to generate a breakdown. This is to protect user privacy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer regarding the app visibility, I did not know you could ask for such permission!

When it comes to the **Gender & Age** data in the Facebook Insights - we have the same volume of logins as we have had for quite some time and now it just, well, disappeared, that is what I find very strange. We did update our mobile SDKs but I cannot see how that would affect this particular section... and that the Geography data is still available confuses me even more.

Comment: There could be many reasons. Not knowing your app, I can't say why. Also note that the breakdown is for New Logins, so while your app might have had the same login volume, the number of new ones might have declined. I'm still seeing them for some apps that I own, and not for others, so I'm pretty sure the system is working as intended.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations, genuinely. Any idea what is the needed volume for this data to be available?