# Different parameters in xcode builds

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2

I'm developing an iOS app with Swift 2 and, like most developers, I have a staging and a production environment, with different servers, URL and settings.

I'm looking for a way to quickly switch between the two configurations as I'm developing the app.

On Android I could use build types and flavors to solve this problem.

**I've read a lot of guides** around the web but all of them were in Obj-C and relied on the macro preprocessor and the #ifdef that was available in Obj-C but isn't in Swift.

There are no clear guides on how to do this in swift and, being a total beginner, I'm not even sure where to start looking.

To recap: what I'm looking for it's a way to switch between two configurations (ex 2 property list files) and to reference the settings contained in those configurations from my code, based on the build I've selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a user defined setting in Target's settings with different values for each scheme (Debug, Release, Ad-Hoc, AppStore etc) and use the user defined variable in info.plist file (or as you call it configurations).

[Check answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29348505/how-to-manage-production-and-development-credentials-using-facebook-ios-sdk/29350439#29350439). Although the question is specific to Facebook App Id setup, the answer applies to any generic setting.

Once you have correct data in info.plist you can [directly use it in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530075/ios-access-app-info-plist-variables-in-code).

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know I had to also modify the info.plist file in order to make the user settings work.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Another way of accessing the user defined build settings could be pre-processor macros [as suggested in these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968919/how-can-i-access-a-user-defined-xcode-build-setting). But getting them through info.plist is much easier and looks relatively cleaner.