# Is app running on test device/simulator/real app store install

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Is there a way to find out during runtime if the app is currently running on a test-device/simulator or from a real app store installation?

I need to implement ad-tracking into the application and during testing/debugging I do not want to send tracking data because this changes the statistics.

But I do not want just to distinguish between DEBUG/RELEASE builds because RELEASE builds are e.g. also used during profiling.

Maybe there is a config set somewhere if the app is from a real app store installation? Or any other way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add following category on `UIDevice` to check whether it is running on device or simulator.

```
- (BOOL)isSimulator {
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    return true;
#else
    return false;
#endif  
}


+ (BOOL)isSimulator {
    return [[self currentDevice] isSimulator];
}
```

**Edit:** I just explored and find out that there is a way to know whether application instance is from app store or not. Here it is:

```
if ([[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"embedded" ofType:@"mobileprovision"]) {
  // not from app store
} else {
  // from app store
}
```

You can refer to this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431994/detect-testflight) for more details.

Comment: Happy to help! Cheers :-)!

Answer (score 2):

If you create separate configuration for your debug, distribution and app store builds (which you ideally should) you can add User-Defined Setting' with different value for each configuration.
This can be exposed to the code as a bundle property by exporting it through info.plist file and you can write your code to handle each configuration differently.

[Refer this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29348505/how-to-manage-production-and-development-credentials-using-facebook-ios-sdk/29350439#29350439) to see this in more detail with screenshots.

Comment: Also a good way, I think I will do this additionally. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following solution:

```
private func isAppStoreDeployedBuild() -> Bool {
    func isSimulator() -> Bool {
        return TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR != 0
    }

    var isAppStore = false
    #if DEBUG
        isAppStore = false
    #else
        if isSimulator() {
            isAppStore = false
        } else {
            // Check if Ad Hoc build e.g. HockeyApp
            if NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("embedded", ofType: "mobileprovision") == nil {
                isAppStore = true
            } else {
                isAppStore = false
            }
        }
    #endif
    return isAppStore
}
```

This covers everything except RELEASE Builds uploaded directly (over USB) to the device. I still can't find a solution to check this (apart from lukya's manual solution).