# Android Facebook v4.0 Login error

Tags: android, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to start a test Android app with FB v4 Login and it just won't work.
All I get is:

> FacebookException: App Not Setup, The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook Login.

I think I did all the configurations that need to be done but this exceptions tells me I missed something.
I registered my app in FB and added added package name, class name, and hash key.
In the manifest I added INTERNET permission+ meta-data application id + FacebookActivity.

In my fragment I have `LoginButton`, `CallbackManager` and `FacebookCallback`.
I called `callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create()` in the `onCreate` method and called `callbackManager.onActivityResult()`.

```
LoginButton loginButton;
CallbackManager callbackManager;
FacebookCallback<LoginResult> callback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        Log.d("TEST", "onSuccess: profile - " + profile.getFirstName());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        Log.d("TEST", "onCancel");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException e) {
        Log.d("TEST", "onError FacebookException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
}

 @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
    loginButton.setFragment(this);
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, callback);
}
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Can anyone see what I have missed?

Comment: Are you working on same machine(pc/laptop) ?

Answer (score 0):

I found thr answer here:
[The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook Login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329250/the-developers-of-this-app-have-not-set-up-this-app-properly-for-facebook-login)

I needed to make the app available to the general public in the Status and review tab on FB Developers.