# Cannot resolve logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground method while integrating Facebook signup/login with Parse

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

I am using parse for backend. I was trying to integrate my app with Facebook. I am following the tutorial given on parse.com. However, when I try to set up login using Facebook, I start having problems. In the tutorial, this small piece of code is given:

```
ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(this, permissions, new LogInCallback() {
 @Override
 public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
 if (user == null) {
   Log.d("MyApp", "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
 } else if (user.isNew()) {
   Log.d("MyApp", "User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
 } else {
   Log.d("MyApp", "User logged in through Facebook!");
 }
 }
});
```

However,when I copied this code in my application, I get an error which says " cannot resolve symbol 'logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground'". When I opened ParseFacebookUtils class in Android studio, it does not have any method called "logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground", but on the website ParseFacebookUtils class does have it. 
Why am I not getting this method ? I am using ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.9.1.jar, which is the latest one. 
Please help me.

Comment: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-Android  re-check instructions

Answer (score 4):

Those are the steps I followed to do the signup / login / linking of users with ParseUsers according to Parse [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#fbusers) and some tips I found on the web.Please check that you didn't miss any step because I had the same problems with you and did all the steps all over again:

- First, I went to [this](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=android) website and created a new application.
- I downloaded the Facebook SDK, I did the steps 4 and 5 and I added my package name and the default class name
- I added the key hashes:

Development Key:

> cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin keytool -exportcert -alias
>   androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\'YOUR NAME'.android\debug.keystore |
>   C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl base64

Release Key:

> cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin keytool -exportcert -alias
>   'NAME YOU GAVE AS ALIAS' -keystore  |
>   C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl base64

- In parse.com inside **Settings** and **Authentication**, I added in **Facebook Application** the **APP ID** that was created in Facebook.
- According to [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started), I did all the steps until **Using Login or Share** (including this).
- I went [here](https://developers.facebook.com/settings/developer/contact/sample-app/) and I added my development hash key.
- In the **Settings** of the application that I created in Facebook, I checked that in the Key Hashes field, there were both Development and Release Keys.
- I used the [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329250/the-developers-of-this-app-have-not-set-up-this-app-properly-for-facebook-login) from the correct answer to make my application live.
- I downloaded the latest SDK of Parse (**1.9.1**) from QuickStart because 1.8 it's not working.
- I added the new .jar file of the **SDK** and the **ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.9.1** inside the `libs` folder of my project and syncronized the **build.gradle** file.
- I added this line in `strings.xml` :
  `<string name="facebook_app_id">1421******</string>`

---

I added this in my `AndroidManifest.xml` inside Application tag:

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
    android:configChanges=
        "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
    android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

and this:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
    android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
```

---

In `build.gradle` of the app I added these inside the android because of some errors with `Diamond` (I am sorry I can't remember the exact error):

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

and I changed the SDK version to be numbers because of some error of undefined variables:

```
minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion 19
```

---

The related `dependencies` inside the same file:

```
compile fileTree(include: 'Parse-*.jar', dir: 'libs')
compile fileTree(include: 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4-*.jar', dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
```

---

- In the activity in which I want to do all those things with facebook I did the below things:

  ```
     Parse.initialize(this, "hoMaK", "wWV193mE");

      FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

      ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(getApplicationContext());

      final List<String> permissions = Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email");

      fb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
      {
          public void onClick(View view)
          {
              proDialog.show();

              ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(HomeActivity.this, permissions, new LogInCallback() {
                  @Override
                  public void done(final ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
                      if (user == null) {
                          Log.d("MyApp", "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");

                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Log-out from Facebook and try again please!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                          ParseUser.logOut();

                          proDialog.hide();
                      }
                      else if (user.isNew()) {
                          Log.d("MyApp", "User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");

                          if (!ParseFacebookUtils.isLinked(user)) {
                              ParseFacebookUtils.linkWithReadPermissionsInBackground(user, HomeActivity.this, permissions, new SaveCallback() {
                                  @Override
                                  public void done(ParseException ex) {
                                      if (ParseFacebookUtils.isLinked(user)) {
                                          Log.d("MyApp", "Woohoo, user logged in with Facebook!");

                                          proDialog.hide();
                                      }
                                  }
                              });
                          }
                          else{
                              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You can change your personal data in Settings tab!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          }
                      } else {
                          Log.d("MyApp", "User logged in through Facebook!");

                          if (!ParseFacebookUtils.isLinked(user)) {
                              ParseFacebookUtils.linkWithReadPermissionsInBackground(user, HomeActivity.this, permissions, new SaveCallback() {
                                  @Override
                                  public void done(ParseException ex) {
                                      if (ParseFacebookUtils.isLinked(user)) {
                                          Log.d("MyApp", "Woohoo, user logged in with Facebook!");

                                          proDialog.hide();
                                      }
                                  }
                              });
                          }
                          else{
                              proDialog.hide();
                          }
                      }
                  }
              });
          }
      });
  ```
- With all the above steps, I can sign up or login using my Facebook account and I am getting a new line in `_User` object in Parse.com in which I can change the data any time I want to (I handle it as a normal sign-up user)

Comment: Great work Marialena. The line `final List<String> permissions = Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email");` was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @ojonugwaochalifu happy this helped you

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem but my issue was supplying an invalid context for the first parameter for `logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground`. Since I am calling it from inside the OnClickListener class, the first parameter should be `MyActivity.this` rather than `this`. You might have the same case.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final List<String> permissions = null;
            ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(SignInActivity.this, permissions, new LogInCallback() { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

"cannot resolve symbol" usually happen from missing dependencies in the gradle file of the app.

As ParseFacebookUtils.jar became a separate jar file, you need to add dependency for it directly, not only add dependency for Parse.jar as before.

Here is what I added.

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include:'ParseFacebookUtilsV4-*.jar')
```

Hope this solve your problem.
Cheers.

Comment: I am doing it, but I still face the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you copy the `ParseFacebookUtilsv4-1.9.4.jar` file to the libs folder of your project:[image]

and your dependecies look like this:

```
dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
   compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
   compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
 }
```

I don't see any reason why `logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground` shouldn't be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the parse latest version then  change to:

```
Parse-1.9.2.
```