# iOS 8, Parse 1.7.2 FBLogin doesn't work for all users

Tags: facebook, authentication, parse-platform, ios8

Using Parse SDK iOS 1.7.2, users that are currently logged in through Facebook on their iPhones, are unable to login through the app using the Parse API.  This is for iOS 8 users.

The Parse login screen appears and the user selects the Facebook button, they grant permission to login and then a Parse error appears in a dialog box.

The only way to work around is have the user delete Facebook from their phone or log out of Facebook and log back in on their phone.  This isn't ideal.

Twitter logins work fine.

Any thoughts on how to get around this problem?

Here is the exact error:

> 015-04-29 21:30:35.109 thirsty[10849:1408273] Failed to log in... Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. com.facebook.sdk:SystemLoginError" UserInfo=0x17e64d10 {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=, expirationDate: (null), refreshDate: (null), attemptedRefreshDate: 0000-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(null)>, NSLocalizedFailureReason=com.facebook.sdk:SystemLoginError, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason=com.facebook.sdk:SystemLoginError, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorInnerErrorKey=Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: Service temporarily unavailable (2)" UserInfo=0x17d54570 {NSLocalizedDescription=The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: Service temporarily unavailable (2)}}

Comment: Can you please add more details? Your code, the error, that would be helpful ;)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was happening...basically the app is in development mode and you can't log in unless you are part of a role there.  This is a Facebook Development Lifecycle thing and not a Parse thing.

[The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook Login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329250/the-developers-of-this-app-have-not-set-up-this-app-properly-for-facebook-login?answertab=active#tab-top)

Make the user a developer/tester through the Facebook portal and try it again.