# Do I need to have my App on Google Play to use the Facebook SDK after exported?

Tags: android, facebook

I built an App with Facebook SDK, today I exported my App to show to some friends and I wasn't able to log in with my account because Facebook didn't recognize my Key hash, I guess.

I was able to register and accept the Application, but when I logged out, and I tried to Log in again, I couldn't do the Log in because my aplication crashed.

I tried to build a new keystore, and I generated a new key hash, but my App still crashing.

Everything was working fine when I was debugging my App using an emulator.

My question is, do I need to have my App hosted on Google Play to put everything working fine?

By now I just have the exported version to see how it works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Nope, you don't have to ... but you should.**

In facebook developer's account, you will have to share your app's publishing key hash when registering it. However, you can use your app before doing so.

I guess you got this message when you showed your app to your friends:

> the developers of this app have not set up this app properly for facebook login

If so, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329250/the-developers-of-this-app-have-not-set-up-this-app-properly-for-facebook-login) .

Comment: But my App is already live...I think that the problem must be the key hash, I generated thousands of hashs but It still not working