# Get facebook birthday not only for my accont

Tags: java, android, facebook

I'm trying to fetch birthday from facebook sdk, I can get my birthday, but I cannot obtain birthday from another accounts. 
I've already set up contact email in Settings and made an app available for general public as it answered here: [Set up app properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329250/the-developers-of-this-app-have-not-set-up-this-app-properly-for-facebook-login).

So, question: For fetching birthdays of another users do I need make "Submit Items for Approval"(and wait when Facebook confirm my app) or I need something another?

Comment: Have the other user granted user_birthday permission to the app?

Comment: Yes, he obtain his birthday from his app on iOS. He has the same problem on iOS, he cannot obtain my birthday. =/ We develop 2 applications 1 - Android, 1 - iOS. And we have the same situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook will give you a user's birthday with the [`user_birthday`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4#reference-user_birthday) permission. This will require a review of your application to ensure you're following their guidelines listed in the docs.

You will not receive access to the user's friends' birthdays, as it's considered their data. Facebook has recently dramatically restricted what you can access in the API for privacy reasons.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be try.