# instead of login to facebook says This app still in development mode

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know the app should be public, but I don't have a facebook account on the iphone, and when I use login with facebook, instead of opening a view for log in, it says the app still in development mode.

I used on making the app fb sdk 4 , the problem occurs only if the iPhone doesn't have facebook programm, so it doesn't get the log in screen .
I need to know what should I add to handle this case so I can get to the login screen if I have no account, instead of saying this message.

Thanks in advance, and no need to put my code here because I used it from stack, and it's the latest version and it's working on the emulator well, but on iphone it says so

Answer (score 0):

The message means your app is in Development Mode -

You need to make your Facebook App ID visible to the public if you want users who aren't administrators/developers/testers of the app to be able to see it and log into it -

You can do this on the Status & Review tab of the App Dashboard - it looks like this:

[image: Status & Review tab of App Dashboard]

More info here (similar cause but a different message): [The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook Login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329250/the-developers-of-this-app-have-not-set-up-this-app-properly-for-facebook-login?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: but in case i don't have a facebook account in my iphone , it won't pop up the login page , it will say that message , this message should only occur if i am logged in with an account that is not an admin nor a tester

Comment: @Alshcompiler: _“this message should only occur if i am logged in with an account that is not an admin nor a tester”_ – if you are not logged in at all, then Facebook can’t tell if the user will be able to access the app or not. Therefor they show the message that the app is not public yet.

Comment: but instead of that it should pop up the log in webview to make the user log in , how to do so in that case to  stop this window to appear and instead the log in view show up