# Facebook Login Not Working After App Launch

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, app-store-connect

I developed an app that uses Facebook login, When i finished it I submitted it for Facebook Review and Facebook approved it, Then I submitted it to apple and now it's on the app store.

The problem is that when other people try to use the Facebook Login the get these errors:

http://postimg.org/image/gcy261c1h
http://postimg.org/image/y49okhrg5

Is there something I need to do after my has app been launch to activate Facebook Login or is it something else?

Comment: check this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329250/the-developers-of-this-app-have-not-set-up-this-app-properly-for-facebook-login

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked