# Facebook Login on a Test App

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, oauth

**Edit2:** The problem is with the SDK not using the Facebook App to display the Auth-Screen, but the WebView. The WebView uses Cookies and had an old user logged in. A user, that is Test User for the Test App, so the message was correct.

I'm trying to login to my Facebook Test App with a Test User (not roles -> testers) using the Facebook iOS SDK.

The problem is similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329250/the-developers-of-this-app-have-not-set-up-this-app-properly-for-facebook-login), but I think the accepted and upvoted answers do not apply to me. First, it's not possible to publish a Test App

> Test Apps allow you to debug and test changes in development. They are always in development mode.

and second the Graph API version probably is older (given the screenshots in that post).

I've tried login with the Main App and that worked. Changed the App ID in xcode and was running into the error

> App Not Setup: This app is still in development mode, and you don't have access to it. Switch to a registered test user or ask an app admin for permissions.

I'm logged in to the Test User with my testing iPhone. And obviously I'm the admin of the Test App (though not using that account to login).

Now the question is: Is it possible to login to a Facebook Test App with a Facebook Test User? Is there probably anything else to setup or to try?

[image: Test User View in dashboard]
[image: Error message in App]

Edit: Added pictures of error message and management for clarity.

Comment: If you see App Not Setup: This app is still in development mode, error, then you have to add the test users to your account to let them test your app.

Comment: Like I said above: I've done exactly that. That's what's surprising me about this behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like said in the last edit:

The problem is with the SDK not using the Facebook App (which would use the system Facebook User) to display the Auth-Screen, but the WebView. The WebView uses Cookies and had an another Test User for a different App Id logged in. So the message was correct after all.

Had to log out in Safari and was able to use the correct user.