# Facebook login in android app works only for admins and testers

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I want to add facebook login ability to my android app.
I created app in developers.facebook.com section and it is marked as published.

For some reason only profiles that are listed as admins, developers and testers can login using facebook.

I don't use any permissions except public_profile.

Comment: Make your apk with same keystore for which you have generated facebook keyhash, for e.g if you have mentioned keyhash in fb developer account of debug.keystore , then u should make apk with that keystore and run on different mobiles by just copying this apk into it. Because  debug.keystore changes for each computer system. Better to make a new keystore of yours and mentioned its key hash into your fb developer account and make a signed apk , then run the application, it will work hope so....:)

Comment: check the link for your solution : http://stackoverflow.com/a/26135600/5541373

Comment: my app is published already

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your facebook app public. 
go to facebook dev page. select your app. go to app review. and make it public

Comment: Also, you can create child apps which you can use for testing purposes.

Comment: can u show whats the page you get when you try to login from your android app?

Comment: the app in play store?

Comment: i meant the screen shot of the error page you see when you try to login as someone who is not added as tester/admin

Answer (score 0):

**Some Suggestion**
Check if Settings> Basic > Android Key Hash are setup.
if not

**HOW TO GET AND SET HASHKEY**
as Refer to Facebook Login Documentation
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/#create_hash

The most preferable solution by me is by code ( **Troubleshooting Sample Apps** )

it will print out the hash key. you can update it on

https://developers.facebook.com/apps/yourFacebookappID/settings/basic/ 
on **Android > Key Hashes** section

**a step by step process on how to get the hashKey.**

1. Firstly Add the code to any oncreate method
   [image]
2. Run The app and Search the KeyHash at Logcat
   [image]

**step by step process on how Update on Facebook Developer.**

3. Open Facebook Developer Page. You need access as to update the Facebook Developer page.
   https://developers.facebook.com
4. Follow the step as follow.[image]