# Retrieve broadcast_start_time field from a live video that has ended

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I would like to retrieve the following field for a live video that has already ended :

broadcast_start_time

1)
It does not show up in the Graph API when loading a video (via /{video-id}?fields=broadcast_start_time) :
(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (broadcast_start_time) on node type (Video)

2)
It shows up in the Live API documentation. But I did not manage to access the Live API yet. I get an error which also does not make sense to me :

(#10) To use live-video-api on behalf of people who are not admins, developers and testers of your app, your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review

I am trying to query the live_videos for a page that I created and that is linked to my app as "App Page". Also my app is still in development so it's not public yet.
So the error does not make sense to me. Should I still ask Facebook team to review my app ? Should I maybe unpublish my page ? Any help welcome.

3)
Does this mean I need to use the Live API to access live videos that have already ended ? As the ended live videos show up like "normal" videos in the posts list, it would seem quite appropriate to be able to query the broadcast_start_time there too ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2) OAuthException code 10 shows up for me when i do "me/?fields=live_videos" with my personal page token, but, if i do the same query with my App Page token everything works fine.

also, i had "wrong access token" for my App trying to publish videos because i haven't made it Public: [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQ0Ax.png)
Make your app public, maybe it will do the thing

P.S. not enough reputation to comment

UPD: take a look [The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook Login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329250/the-developers-of-this-app-have-not-set-up-this-app-properly-for-facebook-login?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks, I also did not select the right token in the Graph API explorer (doh).