# Facebook Login Android SDK ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.gdp.LightWeightLoginParameters

Tags: java, android, facebook

The app works in debug, but it crashes in a loop in release mode. The app is not crashing, the `Facebook` dialog is.

I'm not using `facebook's LoginButton`, but just a normal button and then registering callback with the `LoginManager`.

I have tried `minifyEnabled` false

I searched `google` and haven't seen anyone else with the same class missing.

I'm using `4.27.0` of the `SDK`.

```
12-02 00:32:50.429 3720-4954/? E/Parcel: Class not found when unmarshalling: com.facebook.gdp.LightWeightLoginParameters
                                         java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.gdp.LightWeightLoginParameters
                                             at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                             at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:400)
                                             at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2517)
                                             at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2471)
                                             at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2374)
                                             at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2727)
                                             at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:269)
                                             at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:992)
                                             at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:6702)
                                             at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivityLocked(ActivityStarter.java:336)
                                             at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStarter.java:1094)
                                             at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:5822)
                                             at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:5627)
                                             at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:176)
                                             at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3612)
                                             at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:573)
                                          Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.gdp.LightWeightLoginParameters
                                             at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                             at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:1346)
                                             at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:1406)
                                             at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                             at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
                                             at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:400) 
                                             at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2517) 
                                             at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2471) 
                                             at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2374) 
                                             at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2727) 
                                             at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:269) 
                                             at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:992) 
                                             at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:6702) 
                                             at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivityLocked(ActivityStarter.java:336) 
                                             at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStarter.java:1094) 
                                             at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:5822) 
                                             at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:5627) 
                                             at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:176) 
                                             at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3612) 
                                             at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:573) 
                                          Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
12-02 00:32:50.429 3720-4954/? W/Bundle: Failed to parse Bundle, but defusing quietly
                                         android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: com.facebook.gdp.LightWeightLoginParameters
                                             at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2545)
                                             at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2471)
                                             at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2374)
                                             at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2727)
                                             at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:269)
                                             at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:992)
                                             at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:6702)
                                             at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivityLocked(ActivityStarter.java:336)
                                             at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStarter.java:1094)
                                             at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:5822)
                                             at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:5627)
                                             at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:176)
                                             at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3612)
                                             at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:573)
```

Comment: If the app works in debug but not in release then I am doubting you did not update your SHA in facebook console? Didn't you?

Comment: I did. If the SHA is wrong I would have expected a different error, right?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same kind of error and finally somehow got to know that my app was not properly live on facebook developer console.
For further assistance visit this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/26135600/1925394