# Facebook API Error This app is in development mode 2019

Tags: firebase, authentication

Hi guys i am annouying this error from when i integration facebook login in my ionic app.I tried all things but still get this diloge.Facebook app is still in development mode & don’t have access.

[image]

In my App

[image]

Comment: Which dialogue you mean? You get an error or does the integration not working?

Comment: I try in ionic this is the screen shot of my facebook developer console i also enable this option but still showing the error message in when i try facebook login in my ionic app

Comment: Can you show me the error message?

Comment: yes but in commnet how ok i puttent in my question

Comment: I have the same issue. Even though I switched my app to "LIVE", whenever users are trying to login, they get the "App in development mode" message from Facebook login. This happened to me on a live app, which was working perfectly.

Comment: please up this question so i got the answer fast thankyou

Comment: Have u solved this problem @LalitBaghel? I am facing the same problem, my app is in live mode and facing the same error

Answer (score 0):

In a other stackoverflow I found this

[The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook Login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329250/the-developers-of-this-app-have-not-set-up-this-app-properly-for-facebook-login)

The solution for your problem is to set `status and review` to `ON`

Hope this helps for you!

Comment: i am showing this in my first sceenshot its not working i tried every thing

Comment: Did you try the second solution of the stackoverflow post I send you?

Comment: yes bro tried in 2019 version this option position is shifted which i showing in my first screeshot

Comment: Have any one found a solution?