# "App not setup: This app is still in development mode" Ionic 4 Facebook login

Tags: facebook, ionic-framework, facebook-graph-api, ionic4

I Created my Ionic 4 app with facebook login

everything is fine expect when I make login with facebook

I got thes message "App not setuo: This app is still in development mode"

[image]

and my app is already in live mode

[image]

I don't know if this is a facebook bug or something wrong with my app?

Comment: No one experience this issue?

Comment: Check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329250/the-developers-of-this-app-have-not-set-up-this-app-properly-for-facebook-login

Comment: Have you found a solution @GamalElwazeery ya sadiki?

Comment: Sorry for late, I have just seen this.. yes I solved it by removing the platform and added it again

Answer (score 0):

If app is live mode, check if the app id in packages.json is the same as that in the facebook console.

If so, then check it in both files:  platforms\android\android.json and platforms\android\app\src\main\res\values\facebookconnect.xml. If you have changed it before, sometimes it dont get changed in these files.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by removing the platform and added it again