# Android: "App Not Setup: This app is still in development mode" for Facebook login? in 2020

Tags: android, facebook-login

I know this is a duplicate question but i tried all answer here in this site, (And also let's not forget this famous [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329250/the-developers-of-this-app-have-not-set-up-this-app-properly-for-facebook-login) )
. but all those answer did not work for me, those steps are no longer available in developer panel. I tired to make `status and review to ON` by visiting https://developers.facebook.com/ but no options available .

could any one tell me how to solve this `App Not Setup: This app is still in development mode, for Facebook login`? in 2020. I am not being able to login with different account.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is looking for answer of this question in 2020, here is how i solved it:

1. went to
   https://developers.facebook.com/apps/233157997879534/dashboard/
2. went to basic setting option
3. added icon for my registered app
4. created privacy policy and terms of use, webpages, hosted them
   online and placed their urls
5. added 'Data Protection Officer Contact Information'
6. and finally made app live from development mode.

and that's it , it worked. 
To sum it up,

> You have to make your app live from development mode after completing basic settings.